# Why did my population decrease when I moved home base?

Tags: state-of-decay

I have just recently moved from the Church of the Ascension (the starting home base in Spencer's Mill) to the Snyder Trucking Warehouse in Marshall.

Before I moved I had over 30 people in my group, and after the move I only had 20. Why did my population decrease when I moved home base? Is it possible to find the people I lost and bring them back into the group?

Comment: How in the world did you have 30 people at the church? I never go over 24, even at the trucking warehouse. I would consider this a bug. Have you asked on the forums?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that the Warehouse may not be able to hold that many people. If you made certain modifications to the Church to allow more people to live there, the Warehouse will not have them.

Me never have encountered this, I wouldn't know if it was a glitch or something else. Sorry :l

Comment: Hey, @Jackamope, welcome to Arqade.  I've rolled back your change, since the answer space is saved for answers, not more questions.